# Orthogonal to a vector space

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, lie-algebras, control-theory

Consider the control system
$$
 \dot x(t) = X(x(t)) + u(t)\, Y(x(t)) 
$$
where $X,Y$ are two smooth vector fields and $u$ is a given function.

Consider a reference trajectory $x(.)$ defined on $[0,T]$ such that $Y(x(t))=0$ and
$[X,Y](x(t))=0$.
Then you can suppose that the trajectory $x(.)$ is associated to the function $u\equiv 0$ on $[0,T]$.

Consider the vector space $K(t) = span \{ (ad^kX \cdot Y)(x(t));\,k\ge 0\}$
where $ad^k X\cdot Y = [X,ad^{k-1}X\cdot Y]$ and $ad^0 X\cdot Y = Y$.

How to show that $p(.)$ defined on $[0,T]$ by $\dot p(t) = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x(t),p(t))$ where $H(x,p)=p\cdot (F(x)+u\, G(x))$ is such that $$
p(t) \perp K(t)$$
for all $t\in [0,T]$ ?

---

I would like to show that $p(t)\cdot (ad^kX\cdot Y)(x(t))=0$ for all $t\in [0,T]$.

Ok for $k=0$ by definition of $x(.)$.

Ok for $k=1$ ($p\cdot [X,Y](x(t))=0$) for the same reason.

Ok for $k=2$ because differentiating wrt to the time the equality 
$p(t)\cdot [X,Y](x(t))=0$ leads to $$u(t)=-\frac{p(t)\cdot [X,[X,Y]](x(t))}{p(t)\cdot [Y,[X,Y]](x(t))}$$
and since $u=0$ this implies $p(t)\cdot [X,[X,Y]](x(t))=0$.

But I can't find the general idea ...

Answer (score 1):

**Notation**: Hamiltonian lifts are denoted as : $H_X=p\cdot X$,  $H_Y=p\cdot Y$,  $H_{XY}=p\cdot [X,Y]$,  $H_{XXY}=p\cdot [X,[X,Y]]$, $H_{XXXY}=p\cdot [X,[X,[X,Y]]]\ldots$

---

Using the same idea as the OP, differentiating $p(t)\cdot [X,[X,Y]]=H_{XXY}$  wrt the time leads to
$$
\{H_X + u\, H_Y, H_{XXY}\} = 0
$$
where $\{.,.\}$ are the Poisson brackets.

Since $u\equiv 0$, we have
$$
\{H_X,H_{XXY}\} = 0 \Rightarrow p(t)\cdot [X,[X,[X,Y]]] = p(t)\cdot ad^3 X\cdot Y =0
$$
and so on ...